# Program producing funky output

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that takes in an input stream from std::cin and then fills a map container with all of the words(after removing all punctuation and making them lowercase) from the input along with their frequency.

here is my code...

```
#include "prog4.h"


void clean_entry(const string& s1, string& s2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++) {//loop through the string
        s2[i] = tolower(s2[i]);
    }
}

void get_words(map < string, int >& map1) {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    string s1;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++ , s1 = "") {//loop through 
 entire input
        if (isalnum(input[i]) == 0) {//if its a alphanumeric char
            for (int d = i; isalnum(input[d]) == 0;d++) {//make s1 the 
next set of characters between punctuation
                s1 += input[d];

                if (isalnum(input[d]) != 0)//update i to the next non 
alfanumeric character position
                    i = d;
            }
         }
        clean_entry(s1, s1);
        map1[s1]++;
    }

}

void print_words(const map < string, int >& m1) {
    map<string, int>::const_iterator it;
    cout << "Number of non-empty words: " << m1.size() << '\n';
    int count = 0;
    for (it = m1.begin(); it != m1.end(); it++) {
        if (it->second == 1)
            count++;
    }
    cout << "Number of distinct words: " << count << '\n';
    it = m1.begin();
    for (int y = 0; it != m1.end(); it++,y++) {
        if (y % 3 == 0) {
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << setw(20) << it->first << setw(10) << it->second;
     }
}

int main() {
    map <string, int> m1;
    get_words(m1);
    print_words(m1);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tested the print and clean methods and they both work as expected. The problem I am getting is when I use the get_words method undoubtedly.

As an example when I use the input "Huge Muge Cuge luge" this is what I get as an output...

```
Number of non-empty words: 2
Number of distinct words: 0


                           16                           3
```

I'm not sure what is causing this to happen and after reviewing the code I cant seem to find the problem which is why i'm posting here

Comment: `for (int d = i; isalnum(input[d]) == 0;d++)` does not respect `input` size.

Answer (score 0):

Let me list out few problems which I can observe in your code.

1. The `isalnum` function returns non-zero value for alphanumeric characters.
   That means the statement
   `if (isalnum(input[i]) == 0) {` in function `get_words` should be changed to
   `if (isalnum(input[i]) != 0) {`

Also, statement `for (int d = i; isalnum(input[d]) == 0;d++) {` should be changed to `for (int d = i; isalnum(input[d]) != 0;d++) {`

2. Another problem is that statement `i = d;` will not be executed as when `for` loop break it will skip those lines since conditions are just opposite. You can fix that by moving declaration of `d` out of `for` loop. The modified function should be:

=>

```
void get_words(map < string, int >& map1) 
{
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    string s1;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++ , s1 = "") 
    {
        if (isalnum(input[i]) != 0) 
        {//if its a alphanumeric char
        int d;
            for (d = i; isalnum(input[d]) != 0;d++) 
            {
                s1 += input[d];
            }
            if (isalnum(input[d]) == 0)
                i = d;
        }
        clean_entry(s1, s1);
        map1[s1]++;
    }
}
```